# Setting OpenType features in SVG. Getting Tabular Oldstyle figures to show up in the browser?

Tags: svg, opentype, browser

In Adobe Illustrator there is the OpenType panel <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which lets us set OpenType features for fonts that support them. For example with Montserrat I can set **Figure: Tabular Oldstyle** to have alternate glyphs for numbers that are kerned to line up in tables.

[image: OpenType Figure options for Montserrat font version 5]

Is there a way to get Tabular Oldstyle figures in the browser, in SVG? Is there a setting and if not could I create a subset font to use when I want to show Tabular Oldstyle figures?

Comment: Would converting the text to outlines work for you?

Comment: @BillyKerr Well, in fact for my intended use case it would. It seems the answer is it's not possible to typeset with these features on the Web... but my use case is generating SVGs which I convert to PDFs for print.

Comment: so, I suggest that is what you do.  Open the SVG in vector software such as Illustrator or Inkscape, and convert to outlines for print, save as PDF.  That should work.

Comment: @BillyKerr Unfortunately that won't work, because as text is generated in browser and set as SVG it occupies a certain space. If I change it later in another software to activate Figure: Tabular Oldstyle it will overflow

Comment: I though you meant it didin't work in the browser when you asked  "Is there a way to get Tabular Oldstyle figures in the browser, in SVG?" - If you have the correct fonts installed, it should work in Illustrator or Inkscape. If the font is missing, you will get a font substitution. Perhaps that's the problem?  Not sure if this can really be answered TBH. At least not without access to your computer and the SVG file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get Tabular Oldstyle figures in the browser, in SVG?

Yes!! You can set the `font-variant` property to `tabular-nums`, `oldstyle-nums` or both.

For example:

```xml
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text y="30" font-family="Montserrat, sans-serif" font-variant="oldstyle-nums">1234567890</text>
  <text y="60" font-family="Montserrat, sans-serif" font-variant="tabular-nums">1234567890</text>
  <text y="90" font-family="Montserrat, sans-serif" font-variant="oldstyle-nums tabular-nums">1234567890</text>
  <text y="120" font-family="Montserrat, sans-serif">1234567890</text>
</svg>
```

Renders like this:

[image: Rendering showing the expected properties]

See MDN for [a full list of available settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant).